# How to change Tomcat user in red hat Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

I installed my Tomcat as root user in Linux for testing purpose and It's working fine. I would like to change the user for security purpose, So that owner of log files and other files will be created with new user. How can I do this. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is normally running as `root`.
For security reasons, it is always best to run services only with the minimum privileges that are necessary. Here I have mentioned only those for the Tomcat installation from the source file.

You can modify the Tomcat owner from `root` as follows:

1. Create a group and user for Tomcat.
2. Change ownership of the Tomcat installation files recursively so as to grant them to the user you have just created.

Comment: Can you please help me how to change ownership of the tomcat installation files to user for tomcat?

Comment: I think you are missing the actual part that changes the user that runs Tomcat. It is not useful at all to change ownership of Tomcat files if in the end you run it as a root user.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I just ran across it looking for the same thing and I don't think the answer is exactly right.  This is what I found, change `/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat7`:

```
# from this:
/apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/startup.sh

# to this:
su -c "/apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/startup.sh start" tomcat
```